# Mix of types in array in an interface causing typescript error

Tags: typescript

I am defining three things:

```js
export interface MenuItemLink {
  to: string;
  label: string;
}

type MenuItem = JSX.Element | MenuItemLink;

export interface NavBarProps {
  menuItems: MenuItem[];
}
```

When I try to use it in a map

```js
const items = menuItems.map((item, index) => {
    if (item?.to) {
      return (
        <Link to={item.to} key={index}>
          <span>{item.label}</span>
        </Link>
      );
    } else {
      return item;
    }
  });
```

It gives me a typescript error on item.to:

```
Property 'to' does not exist on type 'MenuItem'.
  Property 'to' does not exist on type 'Element'.ts(2339)
```

But it is an available property on MenuItemLink, which is one of the possible types for MenuItem, so why is it throwing this error?

Comment: Use `if ('to' in item) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for the property with `'to' in item`

```ts
const items = menuItems.map((item, index) => {
    if ('to' in item) {
      return (
        <Link to={item.to} key={index}>
          <span>{item.label}</span>
        </Link>
      );
    } else {
      return item;
    }
  });
```

If menuItems were objects of a class, then you can use instanceof: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#instanceof-narrowing

Comment: `MenuItemLink` is an interface not a class

Comment: @MikeJerred is correct: "'MenuItemLink' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here." The if('to' in item) works. I edited your answer to narrow in on just that.

Comment: Ah yes, good point I forgot about that.